# Spring OAuth2.0- storing access_token in database

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-data

Currently I'm writing a sample code in spring boot to implement OAuth2 to secure my APIs.

I'm storing the access_tokens and refresh_tokens in **oauth_access_token** and **oauth_refresh_token** tables respectively.

Now the **problem** is the tokens when they are stored in the database, they are not the same as the ones which I'm generating from the */oauth/token* endpoint.

So are the tokens automatically encrypted and stored in the database, and if so then how can I access my tokens by decrypting them to access my resources(API).

As there is very limited Spring Security & Spring Boot's documentation to read, so I'm unable to figure out how Spring has internally implemented OAuth2.

**AUTHORIZATION SERVER CODE**

```
@EnableAuthorizationServer
@Configuration
public class AuthServerOAuth2Config extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

    private final AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;
    private final AppConfig appConfig;

    @Autowired
    public AuthServerOAuth2Config(AuthenticationManager authenticationManager, AppConfig appConfig) {
        this.authenticationManager = authenticationManager;
        this.appConfig = appConfig;
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
        clients.jdbc(appConfig.dataSource());
    }

    @Override
    public void configure (AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer security) throws Exception {
        /*
         * Allow our tokens to be delivered from our token access point as well as for tokens
         * to be validated from this point
         */
        security.allowFormAuthenticationForClients().checkTokenAccess("permitAll()");
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
        endpoints
                .authenticationManager(authenticationManager)
                .tokenStore(appConfig.tokenStore()); // Persist the tokens in the database
    }
}
```

*REFERENCE*- *http://dazito.com/java/spring-boot-and-oauth2-with-jdbc#disqus_thread*